# Find all positive integer $a,b,c$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factorial, integers

One day I had a question.

When $a≧b$, $a!+b!+1=c^{ab}$ , find all integer.

**Attempt**

I would use prime factors to compare each side.

$a!+b!+1=b!(a…(b+1)+1)+1$

Comparing each side, $c$’s prime factor is bigger than b.

$b^{ab}<a!+b!+1<2a!<2(\frac{a}{2})^a$

$b^b<a$

But I can't think next step.

Would you mind solving my question?

Comment: I think there is something off in the last inequality, as $a=b=1$ and $c=3$ is a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be positive integers such that
$$a!+b!+1=c^{ab}.$$
Without loss of generality $b\leq a$, and clearly $c>1$.

If $a=1$ then $b=1$ and so $c=3$, yielding the solution
$$(a,b,c)=(1,1,3).$$
If $a=2$ then $b!+3=(c^b)^2$, where either $b=1$ or $b=2$. A quick check yields only
$$(a,b,c)=(2,1,2).$$
If $a\geq3$ then $2a!+1\leq a^a$ and so
$$c^{ab}=a!+b!+1\leq2a!+1\leq a^a,$$
which shows that $c^b\leq a$. Then $c^b$ divides $a!$, from which it follows that $c^b$ also divides
$$c^{ab}-a!=b!+1.$$
If $b\geq2$ then this implies that $c\leq b$, so that $c$ divides $b!$. Then $c$ also divides
$$c^{ab}-a!-b!=1,$$
but then $c=1$, a contradiction, as we already noted that $c>1$. Then $b=1$ and so $c=2$ and we see that $a!+2=2^a$. Then from $a\geq3$ it follows that $a!\equiv2\pmod{4}$, and so $a=3$, yielding the solution
$$(a,b,c)=(3,1,2).$$

Comment: I can follow most of the argument given here, except the part: "If $b\geq 2$, then (1) implies that $c\leq b$". Could you please expand on that part?

Comment: @Prism If $b\geq2$ then $b^b>b!+1$. So if $c^b$ divides $b!+1$ then surely $c\leq b$.

Comment: awesome! Your idea that compare a and c is an amazing idea.Thank you.